# How to get specific key:values from an object inside and object inside and object into new JSON

Tags: javascript

I'm having a difficult time being able to access data that's double nested into an object. This is an example of the JSON I'm working with

```json
{
    "obj": {
        "obj": [
            {
                "cart": "2762",
                "name": "Joe",
                "testing": "no"
            },
            {
                "cart": "214945",
                "name": "Larry",
                "testing": "yes"
            }
        ],
        "offset": 0,
        "total": 9715
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to access the data and put each object into it's own object at the top level but only the key:values I want.

For example

```
data = [
  { name: 'joe', testing: 'no',},
  { name: 'Larry', testing: 'yes'},
]
```

I have tried

```
const data = original_data.obj.obj.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value }));
console.log(data);
```

And the result was two undefined objects

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

Comment: `data = original_data.obj.obj.map(...)`

Comment: I tried const data = original_data.obj.obj.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value }));
console.log(data); and got two undefined objects

Comment: `.map(({name, testing}) => {name, testing})`

Comment: Your objects don't have any properties named `key` and `value`.

Comment: I think you may be looking for `Object.entries()` to convert an object to an array of keys and values.